# Disable PIN Unlock with Certificates and WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: lock-screens, certificates, wpa2

I want to use a Samsung device (4.1.2) within WPA2-Enterprise. When I install a certificate in order to connect to the RADIUS server, the phone immediately wants me to set up a PIN to lock it. I can't disable this setting afterwards, only by removing the certificate. Which locks me out of the wifi.

Is there any way to deactivate this behaviour of android and to keep the phone usable without entering a PIN to unlock it?

Comment: That's the whole point of certificates, right? That the publisher grants you permission to something (RADIUS server), but under their conditions. Circumventing this might be illegal behaviour, so watch out with that. Sounds like there is a valid reason to have a PIN protecting whatever may be seen there. If there isn't a valid reason, you should pick it up with the publisher and ask if the PIN restriction can be removed from the certificate.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well this is not the problem that the PIN is no longer protecting something. The device is given to people who are always within closed rooms. And after booting it starts immediatly some kind of container which can't be turned off. it's just some extra comfort for specific persons. But as I said. Thank you for this tip.

Comment: Similar question here: [Certificate Install without mandatory PIN lockscreen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25491/16575)