# PIN on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

I have managed to install a wifi certificate, and it forced me to set up a PIN for the lock screen. I absoluterly DON'T want that, because it is very annoying to have to type it every time I unlock the device, which I do quite often. Only all other options save for Password are not selectable. Why is that and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
**Looks like it may be the wifi certificate, it's forcing a higher level of security (pin or password). There's a highly technical discussion about that at this older question: [Certificate Install without mandatory PIN lockscreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25491/certificate-install-without-mandatory-pin-lockscreen)**

**So you 'll probably either have to deal with the pin or get rid of the wifi certificate.**

...
...
...

*Go to **Settings >> Security >> Device Administrators**. See if anything other than Android Device Manager is checked. Uncheck it if there is, and check the screen lock options again. 
Also, when posting questions like this, it's always best to also mention what Android Firmware you're running (KitKat, Lollipop...) and your device. Somethings settings option can differ between firware versions and/or devices.*

...
...

Comment: Nope, nothing else checked.

Comment: How do I find out what firmware I have?

Comment: Settings >> About Phone (look at Android Version)

Comment: Settings>General>About Device says "Android version 4.4.2, Kernel version 3.4.0-2688263 dpi@SWDD6216 #1 Wed Sep 3 13:38:08 KST 2014" and more stuff.

Comment: @MickG: have you had a look at my updated answer yet?

Comment: I suggest you always notify people of edits as they may not notice them otherwise :). I saw the edit just after seeing your comment today, but being short of time I haven't yet read anything but the question from it. I certainly will read it sooner or later. Thx.

Comment: @MickG my previous comment was my notification to you. I made that comment directly after I made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot avoid that on a not-rooted device, as user-certificates enforce this. On a rooted device, you could make it a "trusted system certificate", and thus not trigger the described behavior – assuming you're talking about a certificate as shown in *Settings › Security › Certificates* in the "user" tab. The corresponding system certificates are stored in `/system/etc/security/cacerts/`.